# How to rotate a photo on iPhone only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have an iPhone app I am testing on my iPhone and iPad. When running my app adhoc, the problem is that when the photo loads on my iPhone 4 during ad hoc testing, the photo loads on its side; the photo loads fine on iPad mini.

The following line of code successfully rotates the fullscreen image on iPhone, but conversely rotates the image when I test on iPad.

```
//successfully rotates but also over rotates on iPad
PhotoView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);
```

Can someone help me set up conditional statements so I can use my `CGAffineTransforMakeRotation` line of code only on iPad?

I have so far tried the following conditional statements but they don't work for some reason: i.e. only the iPhone if statement works and overrides the iPad if statement so the iPhone statement is carried out on both devices.

```
//does not successfully set the bk for iPad but does for iPhone. The iPad statement is overridden and the iPhone statement is carried out on both platforms. Any ideas?

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
}
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
}
```

This second conditional statement also doesn't work...

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
    {
        // iPhone, iPod Touch
    }
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
        // iPhone 5
    }
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height ==  667) {
        // iP6
    }
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height ==  736) {
        // iP6+
    }
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024) {
        // iPad
    }
```

My question: does anyone have code to rotate an image on iPhone but not iPad?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an iPhone app, it is *always* "on an iPhone". Even when running on the iPad, it is running on a virtual iPhone in emulation mode. It is impossible for it to behave differently on the different devices; it is running on just one device type, as far as it can tell.

If you don't like that, make it a Universal app. Now it runs natively on iPad and your tests will work.

Comment: Good point but why is it loading on its side in the first place (on iPhone) but not iPad  ? And I thought code could check for the current device regardless of the build settings? I will change to universal and see if it runs smoothly, thanks. Update in progress ...